# Known flaws in Signal app's security

Tags: signal

Are there any known exploits in Signal's encryption protocol that could lead to messages being decrypted, or any other compromising information being released?

Answer (score 5):

**No,** there are no known public flaw in Signal at the time of writing of this answer.

Source: [there was only one CVE for Signal (for Android), in 2018.](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/search/results?form_type=Advanced&results_type=overview&seach_type=all&query=cpe:2.3:a:signal:messenger:*.*:*:*:*:*:android:*:*) The only one listed (fixed in version 4.25.0 the 14 Aug 2018) could leak photos attached to disappearing messages.

Answer (score 2):

It's not so much a flaw but more an expected and documented but nonetheless surprising behavior: since Signal uses the phone number as an ID, it is possible to identify whether a Signal account tied to a specific phone number is a member of a group that you are yourself a member of.

This has apparently been used by Chinese government agencies to identify dissidents:

1. Get yourself added to the "subversive" group chat.
2. Check a list of suspected dissident's phone numbers against the members of the group.

[I can't find the article nor remember the details, so I'm leaving this as a community wiki. If someone knows the details, please feel free to edit.]

Comment: Is this a weakness, though? If you are a member of a group, it's not a weakness that other members know who you are. Sure, it could be architected differently, but I wouldn't call this a weakness of the *protocol*.

Comment: @schroeder "or any other compromising information being released"

Comment: @psitae then you might need to define what you mean, because the identity of those you are communicating with is not "compromising information". Neither is it a "flaw". Your question is now sounding like "tell me all the potentially bad things about Signal".

Comment: This is not an "exploit in Signal's encryption protocol"